# How to get the node path through XMLreader

Tags: php, xml

I know how to get the node path via DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadXML('<fruits><fruit><name>Apple</name><name>Banana</name></fruit></fruits>');

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node){
    // e.g. $node->getNodePath();
};
```

My question is: I need to get all the nodes + the number of times it occurs in a file, and I have VERY large files.

An example file is this:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <properties>
            <property></property>
            <property></property>
        </properties>
    </product>
    ...
</products>
```

- the node `<products>` appears 1 time (because it's the root node)
- the node `<product>` appears 60 000 times
- the node `<property>` appears 120 000 times (2 times per product)

**WARNING:** because each file is different, I do NOT have the name of the root node! in this example, it's `<products>` but it can be something else to). To get the name of the root node, I use this code:

```
$simpleXML = simplexml_load_file(<-- filename goes here -->);
$root = $simpleXML->getName();
```

I found this repository: https://github.com/dkrnl/SimpleXMLReader

Then I use this code:

```
$reader = new SimpleXMLReader;

$reader->open(<!-- filename goes here -->);

$reader->registerCallback($root,function($reader){

    $xml = $reader->expandDomDocument();

    foreach($xml->childNodes as $child){

        list($nodes,$counter) = getChildrenOfAllNodes($child,$nodes,$counter);

    };

};

$reader->parse();

$reader->close();
```

And this is my "getChildrenOfAllNodes"-function:

```
    function getChildrenOfAllNodes(DOMNOde $node,$nodes,$counter){

        foreach($node->childNodes as $child){

            if($child->hasChildNodes()){

                list($nodes,$counter) = getChildrenOfAllNodes($child,$nodes,$counter);

            };

            if(strpos($child->nodeName,'#') === false){

                if(array_key_exists($child->nodeName,$nodes)){

                    $nodes[$child->nodeName]['count'] += 1;

                    $nodes[$child->nodeName]['path'] = $child->getNodePath();

                }else{

                    $nodes[$child->nodeName] = array(
                        'name'  => $child->nodeName,
                        'path'  => $child->getNodePath(),
                        'count' => 1
                    );

                }

                $counter++;

            };

        };

        return array($nodes,$counter);

    };
```

It works with files around 1000 nodes, but files with more than 1000 nodes, it keeps processing.

My question is: **is there a (better) solution (than this one) to get all the names + nodepaths in a xml-file for very large files?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

XMLReader is the way to go. But you should not expand the whole document (That is what happends in the example).

You use `XMLReader:read()` and `XMLReader:next()` to navigate to the nodes that represent you records (`product`). Expand that node into DOM and use DOM methods/xpath to fetch data, `DOMNode::getNodePath()` to fetch the partial node path.

Prefix that path manually with the outer structure, e.g. change it according to it.

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('php://stdin');

$document = new DOMDocument();
$xpath= new DOMXpath($document);

while ($reader->read() and $reader->localName != 'fruit') { 
}

if ($reader->localName == 'fruit') {
  $counter = 0;
  do {
    $fruit = $reader->expand($document);
    $counter++;
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('name', $fruit) as $name) {
      var_dump(
        [ 
          'name' => $name->textContent,
          'local_path' => $name->getNodePath(),
          'path' => preg_replace(
            '(^/(\w+))', '/fruits$2['.$counter.']', $name->getNodePath()
          )  
        ]
      );
    }
  } while ($reader->next('fruit'));
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "Apple"
  ["local_path"]=>
  string(14) "/fruit/name[1]"
  ["path"]=>
  string(18) "/fruits[1]/name[1]"
}
array(3) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "Banana"
  ["local_path"]=>
  string(14) "/fruit/name[2]"
  ["path"]=>
  string(18) "/fruits[1]/name[2]"
}
```

If you do not know the nodes itself you will have to iterate using the structure, check the node types and store the found node names into variables.

```
$nodeNames = [
  'list' => NULL,
  'item' => NULL
];
while ($reader->read()) {
  if ($reader->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
    if (NULL === $nodeNames['list']) {
      $nodeNames['list'] = $reader->localName;
    } elseif (NULL === $nodeNames['item']) {
      $nodeNames['item'] = $reader->localName;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}

var_dump($nodeNames);
if ($reader->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && $reader->localName == $nodeNames['item']) {
  $counter = 0;
  do {
    $item = $reader->expand($document);
    var_dump($item->getNodePath());
  } while ($reader->next($nodeNames['item']));
}
```